# How to un-tab whole block?

Tags: python, eclipse

Mean having a block with extra tab in each line  how could I remove this tab using eclipse   ?

For example  -

```
    while(1):
        if(data == "ACK"):
            break
```

convert to  -

```
while(1):
    if(data == "ACK"):
        break
```

I use **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.** with **PyDev 2.7**

Comment: Have you tried selecting all three lines and hitting Shift + Tab?

Comment: @MarcBaumbach: Great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting all three lines and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> should un-indent the code block.